# PowerCLI, issues with where statment

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am running this code in PowerCLI to output VM's that require VM-tool upgrades.

```
 Get-VM | where {$_.powerstate -ne “PoweredOff” } | Get-VIew | where {$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus -ne “guestToolsCurrent”}| select Name, @{ Name=”ToolStatus”; Expression={$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus}}
```

This works great but I also need to exclude some additional information such as "guestToolsUnmanaged" and "guestToolsNotInstalled"

I have tried using something like this:

```
 Get-VM | where {$_.powerstate -ne “PoweredOff” } | Get-VIew | where {$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus -ne “guestToolsCurrent” -and “guestToolsNotInstalled” }| select Name, @{ Name=”ToolStatus”; Expression={$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus}}
```

However this just outputs the same information as the previous block of code, I tried adding "-and -ne" but this is invalid syntax.  Can anyone confirm the correct syntax for joining multiple statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the $_.SomeObject each time:

```
... where {$_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus -ne "guestToolsCurrent" -and $_.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus -ne "guestToolsNotInstalled" } ...
```

Comment: Yep that did it.  Thanks.  So obvious now.